# How to replace a vertical blind clip?

Tags: blinds

I have a vertical blinds, but one of the blinds is missing and needs to be replaced. I have some pictures of it below. The problem is the plastic see through clip that is holding the blind. I don't know where I would buy one. In the second image, it sort of has a circle shape but one side is cut almost like a half moon shape. Does anyone know where to buy it and the blind?

Preferably from known stores like blindstogo, or home depot/staples/home hardware, etc...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Last time I needed a small part for a vertical blind (not this part, another) my local blind-making store gave me a few in exchange for me putting some coins in their charity box.

Comment: Do you know the name of the plastic clip?

Comment: No, sorry. I generally take broken parts with me to make sure I get the right replacements.